# ServiceStack AutoQuery, Implicit/Explicit Queries

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have the following Request DTO:

```
[Route("/processresults")]
public class FindProcessResults : QueryBase<ProcessResult, ProcessResultDto>  {}
```

`ProcessResult` has a property named `Id` (Int32). I have two `ProcessResults` in my database, Id 1 and 2.

When I perform a GET to /processresults?Id=1 I get a single `ProcessResult` returned. Great.

However when I POST this JSON I get two `ProcessResults` returned. The query is not executing. When I add the property `Id` to `FindProcessResults` the JSON call does work, however I have not set `EnableUntypedQueries` to false.

```
PostData: {"Id":"1"}
```

What could be the issue here?

Bonus points, if I make a `POST` with Form Data I get the following exception:

```
{
   ResponseStatus: {
     ErrorCode: "RequestBindingException",
     Message: "Unable to bind request",
     StackTrace: " at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.CreateRequest(IRequest httpReq, IRestPath restPath)\ \ at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes, String operationName)"
   }
}
```

However if I do the same (a post) with x-www-form-urlencoded the query works as intended (returns a single result).

Conclusion: Whilst I can resolve this issue by adding the parameter I wish to query by (Id) to the typed request, this defeats the purpose of what I am trying to achieve, a generic query mechanism for my data store. The functionality already exists for the GET version of the request.

I believe it is to do with the implementation of AutoQueryServiceBase:

```
        public virtual object Exec<From>(IQuery<From> dto)
        {
            SqlExpression<From> q;
            using (Profiler.Current.Step("AutoQuery.CreateQuery"))
            {
                q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(dto, Request.GetRequestParams());
            }
            using (Profiler.Current.Step("AutoQuery.Execute"))
            {
                return AutoQuery.Execute(dto, q);
            }
        }
```

This is using `Request.GetRequestParams()` which will return parameters from the Query String or the Form Parameters, whilst a JSON request is attempting to be deserialized into `<From> dto`. The `From` type `FindProcessResults` has no `Id` property and so it is not populated and passed to the Query.

**Requested HTTP Request/Response:**

**Request**

```
POST /processresults HTTP/1.1
Host: localocl
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 36d4b37e-0407-a9b3-f2f2-5b024d7faf7f

{"Id":1}
```

**Response**

```
Cache-Control → private
Content-Length → 1580
Content-Type → application/json; charset=utf-8
Date → Mon, 03 Nov 2014 21:20:43 GMT
Server → Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Vary → Accept
X-AspNet-Version → 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By → ServiceStack/4.033 Win32NT/.NET, ASP.NET

{"Offset":0,"Total":2,"Results"....
```

Comment: Can you please POST the full HTTP Request/Response of the query that's failing using something like Fiddler or WebInspector.

Comment: Thanks for your help @mythz I have attached the request/response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should strongly consider using `GET` requests for consuming AutoQuery services which is more appropriate HTTP Verb to use, that's also more cacheable and introspectable.

If you want to `POST` and you don't want to use a HTML Form POST (i.e. `x-www-form-urlencoded` Content-Type) you will need to formalize the parameters by adding them to the Request DTO:

```
[Route("/processresults")]
public class FindProcessResults : QueryBase<ProcessResult, ProcessResultDto>  
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Otherwise it will try to deserialize the JSON into an empty DTO where any non-existing properties are ignored.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So it the deserialization into the Request DTO that is stopping this from working. I realise a GET is a better verb to use, however its so easy to create a javascript object and post it as JSON. I will have to look at easier ways of creating query strings in javascript. Thanks for your time and effort of responding :)